# css transform with multiple attributes works on firefox but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to add style transform rotate as well as scale to a set of images. I used

```
img.style = "transform: rotate(" + object[k].angle + "deg) scale(0.2);";
```

Using this the transform attribute rotate and style work fine in firefox, but when running on chrome it dooesnt work. So I tried using

```
img.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + object[k].angle + "deg) scale(0.2);";
```

While using this in firefox and chrome only the scaling works. Since I am using different rotation angles for different image from a json I'm finding it difficult to call them into style sheet.css as an alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the semicolon within the string. Chrome treats this as part of the style you're setting and ignores it as it believes it to be invalid. Removing it works fine in Chrome. Change:

```
img.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + object[k].angle + "deg) scale(0.2);";
                                                                          ^
```

To:

```
img.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + object[k].angle + "deg) scale(0.2)";
```

Comment: I not see the difference @james